# Jquery Autocomplete (devbridge) and Searchable input

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm currently using these two plugins together:

https://github.com/stidges/jquery-searchable

https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

My problem is that when I select an option from the autocomplete dropdown (**via mouseclick**), it fills the textarea but does not trigger the jquery-searchable filter action.

However, if I select an option from the autocomplete dropdown **with the keyboard** (using the down arrow key), jquery-searchable works.

One thing to note is that the mouseclick method "works" if I do any sort of keypress in the text box after selecting an option, whether that be entering a space, or simply moving the cursor with the left/right arrow keys. Upon any of these actions taking place, jquery-searchable kicks in and the searchable items are filtered as usual.

I'm guessing there must be a difference between the way a click and keyboard-select write the data to the input field.

On the other hand, if I could simulate a keypress inside the input after I select an option. I don't want to have to rely on hackish keypress simulations if possible, but for question's sake, here's what I did try (doesn't work):

```
$('#dpt-search').autocomplete({
      lookup: dpts,
      minLength: 0,
      onSelect: function (suggestion) {
          $('#dpt-search').trigger('keypress');
      }
});
```

So basically,

1.) Is there a way to make jquery-autocomplete option select via mouseclick operate the same way option selection works via keyboard?

2.) If not, is there a way to ensure some simulated keyboard activity occurs within the input element after I select it, to trigger jquery-searchable?

---

Here is the live example: http://cpira.tamucc.edu/membership/findrep/

Try typing in "Center" into the search field, then mouse-click the first option. The field will auto-fill but `searchable` won't filter the list.

Clear the field, and search "Center" again, but this type use your keyboard down-arrow key. Each selection (as you move down the list with the arrow key) updates the `searchable` filter.

Comment: Can you share a link to a hosted site or jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the jQuery but change `keypress` to `change` or `keyup`. According to the [source](https://github.com/stidges/jquery-searchable/blob/master/jquery.searchable.js) starting at line 61 (specifically 64), the bind events for the search are `keyup` and `change`. I'd also add a `.focus()` before `.trigger()` to be sure that the input is selected/focused.